# SSL Certificate for Delphi Application - Is it required to enable the security?

Tags: php, delphi, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

So I've just installed XAMPP today, and I noticed that the index.php had a check to see if it was accessed through HTTPS. Before that, I thought that in order to use SSL security, you need a certificate, but I am in doubt now.

At this point (Please do correct me, that is the whole point of this question!), my own research has led me to believe that the Certificate only provides information about the location you are accessing. If no Cert is found, it is up to the client to determine if he/she trusts the connection.

The XAMPP index page contains this check:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/xampp/');
    exit;
?>
```

Alright, so I access my Localhost through `https://localhost`, and the Firefox "Do you trust this website?" page appeared (and the question is: Can I trust myself? ;) ).

After that, I created my own little `test.php`, with the following code:

```
<?php
  echo "Hi. \n";
  if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']))
  {
   echo "Your Firstname is ".$_POST['firstname']." and your Lastname is ".$_POST['lastname'];
   echo "\r\n\r\n";
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        echo "You are using SSL, arentcha? :)";
    } else {
        echo "Hmm.. No SSL!";
    }

  }

?>
```

I then created a Delphi application that connects to `http://localhost/test.php`, and to `https://localhost/test.php`, aswell as `http://jeffijoe.com/test.php` and `https://jeffijoe.com/test.php` with the `TIdHTTP` control (and for the SSL, I hooked up a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` to the `TIdHTTP`'s `IOHandler` property.

Here is the code for that:

```
Var
  Src : TStringlist;
  location: String;
begin


 if RadioButton1.Checked then
 location := 'localhost' else location := 'jeffijoe.com';

 if RadioButton3.Checked then
 Protocol := 'http' else Protocol := 'https';    

  Memo1.Clear;

  Src := TStringlist.Create;
  try
  Src.Add('firstname=Jeff&lastname=Hansen');
  Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post(Protocol+'://'+location+'/test.php',Src);
  finally
    Src.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Here are the results:

**http://localhost/test.php** - Expected output

**https://localhost/test.php** - Expected output (It aknowlegdes I am using HTTPS!)

**http://jeffijoe.com/test.php** - Expected output

**https://jeffijoe.com/test.php** - Fail! 404 Not Found!

My jeffijoe.com is hosted on a regular shared hosting account.

So - the questions are: Was the HTTPS to Localhost truly "secure"? And how come the HTTPS connection to the Jeffijoe.com location failed, when it didnt on my Localhost? How about the Certificates? Are they required? Is it possible to set up the secured connection without having to purchase an overpriced certificate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The connection is safe from sniffers, ie what goes over the wire is encrypted.  But as the certificate is self-signed, there is no guarantee that the other side is really who they pretend to be, that's exactly the point of certificates: a third party guarantees that the other side has been verified to be who they pretend to be.

The reason it worked on your local XAMPP box is that it carries a so-called self-signed certificate, and the server infrastructure to manage https communications, both of which are more than probably lacking on your hosted site.

In the end it depends on what you want to achieve: if the communication just has to be safe from sniffing, self signed certificates work just fine.  If you need to prove you are who you pretend to be, you need a certificate issued by a specialized company.

EDIT: to make this exercise more interesting: the cert system can work both ways, ie the server proves to you that it is genuine, and thanks to a so-called client certificate you can prove to the server you are who you pretend to be.  Depending on your use case exploring cllient-side certifcates could be quite useful, but be warned it's not easy.

Comment: My Delphi application will connect to either **my** host, or the clients own host, so the whole trust issue is not a problem. I just need to secure the connection in case the client has some curious-eyes-software he/she is not aware about. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Jeff I'd say that in your use case a self-signed certificate is all you need, but go have a look at http://www.cacert.org/ as well.

Comment: The thing is, my app will be a consumer product, where the customer has to install my PHP script on his own hosting account. They wont know how to generate an SSL cert, heck they wont even know what that is. :P

Comment: The Client-sided Win32 part of my product, connects to the PHP script on the customers server. Unless the customer is skizzo, the whole verification stuff wont be necessary. I just need a secured connection so the customer knows that the connection is secure at all times. :)

Comment: If you install the application on a hosting account you need to ensure the acct supports ssl - in may cases it will be a nonfree option.  If the account is ssl enabled, your hosting company will sort out all these details for you.

Comment: What details are we talking about? Obviously it has to be as easy as possible for the client. :)

Comment: My cPanel has an SSL panel, where I can generate keys.

Comment: The client orders an ssl enabled hosting account, and the hosting company will hand it over ready to run, just dump your content in it and surf to it with https://....  See http://www.ovh.co.uk/shared_hosting/shared-ssl.xml for an example

Comment: @Jeff let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1286/discussion-between-fvu-and-jeff)

Comment: A self-signed certificate doesn't protect from man-in-the-middle attacks because anybody can generate a cert with exactly the same data. You need a CA chain both parties trusts - it could be you own if the other party agrees.